# .Net Core 3.1 MVC Ajax File Upload (without using a form object)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

I am using .NET Core 3.1 MVC infrastructure.

I want to upload files to Azure Blob Storage with ajax.

But there is no form object in my View.cshtml. It should not be a form object either, because another operation of mine does not allow me to use a form.

Isn't it possible to upload files with ajax without using form object?

Microsoft has an example, but the form has always been used. Isn't it possible to do this without posting a form object?

Microsoft Source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1

I might have friends who don't understand what I mean by form. I am sharing the sample code block.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> 
  <input asp-for="FileUpload.FormFile" type="file">             
  <input asp-page-handler="Upload" class="btn" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Thank you so much,

Comment: It is browser sandbox restriction, you cannot upload file browsed from user's file system without using form. It is possible to generate file content in memory on client side and send it as file upload, but when choosing file from file system you must follow the rules, you can only customize how it looks and feels.

Comment: When  sending requests via AJAX you don't need a `<form>` tag (although it can make things simpler), but in your case you will still need the `<input type="file"` so that the user can select what to upload. Does that help? It's a bit unclear what you're trying to say. But what exactly is the restriction which _prevents_ you from having a `<form>` tag? That sounds very strange and unusual...can you give details? I wonder if this is not really a genuine restriction. However, yes you can do without the `<form>` part quite easily if you need to.

Comment: @ADyson I cannot use a form due to an obligation. It is related to the structure I use. This part is very clear. I will not use forms, but of course I will use an HTML element. So an <input type = "file"> could of course be. I can use all HTML elements. I just don't want to post this in the form. Because I also have data that is not in the form. And many operations are turning. It is not possible to include these operations in form. There is such a requirement

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev It is mandatory to use a form object on the view side when uploading files to a server. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: @EnesGezici Alexey is referring to the `<input type="file"` element. Alexey's point is similar to mine - you must use that element to allow the user to choose the file, but because you are using AJAX for the upload, you do not need a `<form` element to belong with it. All you need to do is, in your Javascript, when you want to do the upload, get the value from the file input element, put it into a JS `FormData` object along with all your other parameters you want to send to the server, and then you have everything you need to send the request to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upload files directly from the web page directly and not using the form object: use `file` as you wish.

To do this, you need to get a SAS token with write permission and on the web page, you can use [Azure storage JS SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-javascript-client-libraries-legacy#add-the-blob-storage-client-library) to upload files directly.

You can go through [this official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-javascript-client-libraries-legacy) to do this.

I also write a simple demo with uploading progress for you for a quick test :

```
<html>

<body>

    <button id="select-button">Select and upload files</button>
    <input type="file" id="file-input" multiple style="display: none;" />
    <div id="showProgress"></div>


    <p><b>Status:</b></p>
    <p id="status" style="height:160px; width: 593px; overflow: scroll;" />

    
</body>
<script src="./azure-storage-blob.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>

const selectButton = document.getElementById("select-button");
const fileInput = document.getElementById("file-input");
const status = document.getElementById("status");

const reportStatus = message => {
    status.innerHTML += `${message}<br/>`;
    status.scrollTop = status.scrollHeight;
}

const accountName = "<your storage account name>";
const sasToken = "<your sas token without '?' >";
const containerName = "<your container name>";
const containerURL = new azblob.ContainerURL(
    `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}?${sasToken}`,
    azblob.StorageURL.newPipeline(new azblob.AnonymousCredential));

const uploadFiles = async () => {
    try {
        reportStatus("Uploading files...");
        const promises = [];
        for (var fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < fileInput.files.length; fileIndex++) {
            const file = fileInput.files[fileIndex];
            const blockBlobURL = azblob.BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, file.name);

            document.getElementById('showProgress').innerHTML += file.name +":<div id='progress-"+ file.name +"'></div>"
            

            var blobUploadOptions = {
                blockSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB block size
                parallelism: 20, // 20 concurrency
                progress: function (ev) {
                    var percentdone = ((ev.loadedBytes / file.size) * 100);
                    var progessItem = document.getElementById('progress-' + file.name);
                    progessItem.innerHTML = percentdone.toFixed(2) + "%";                     
                }
            };
            var promise = azblob.uploadBrowserDataToBlockBlob(
                azblob.Aborter.none, file, blockBlobURL,blobUploadOptions);
            
            promise.then((result)=>{
                var progessItem = document.getElementById('progress-' + file.name);
                progessItem.innerHTML += "  <a href="+result._response.request.url+">file link</a>" 
                
            });

            promises.push(promise);
        }
        await Promise.all(promises);

        reportStatus("Done.");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

selectButton.addEventListener("click", () => fileInput.click());
fileInput.addEventListener("change", uploadFiles);


</script>

</html>
```

Please make sure that you have [enabled CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-javascript-client-libraries-legacy#setting-up-storage-account-cors-rules) before you run this demo.

Result:

[image]

[image]

Let me know if you have any further questions.